Why am I unable to re-flag a post after my previous flag has been attended to?
According to the status-completed Meta SE post “Once a flag is cleared from the mod queue, the same post cannot be re-flagged”, it says that "Once a mod has attended to your previous flag, you may then flag a post again."
However, I recently tried to flag a post as "in need of moderator intervention" on a Meta site, and I ran into an issue. Despite my last flag (on 2024-03-09) being marked as "helpful," the system wouldn't let me submit a new flag for the same post. (My flag message is the same as my previous one.) It gave me an error message saying, "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention," even though I had no pending flags on that post.
Is this a bug, or am I missing something here? Based on the Meta SE post I mentioned, I should be able to flag the post again after a moderator has attended to my previous flag. But the system seems to be preventing me from doing so.
Could someone please clarify this for me? If it's not a bug, why can't I flag the post again, even though a prior status-completed meta post suggests that I should be able to?

Unable to reproduce. I'm able to custom flag a post here that I've already flagged with a custom flag which was deemed helpful.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Hmm. Maybe the issue is specific to the post I mentioned. Looking at my flag history, I was also able to do this (re-flagging a custom flagged post previously marked as "helpful"), but just not on this specific post.

Unable to reproduce on SO or MSO. I wonder if you're actually being blocked because of the flag content, eg "upvotes".

@Laurel I was able to flag the post with a similar flag text, including the word "upvotes,"  prior to my second flag attempt.

I think I've uncovered a bit of a quirk with the flagging system. It seems that the system won't allow you to re-flag a post if you use the same flag message as a previous flag, even if that previous flag was marked as "helpful."
Once I rephrased my flag message slightly, I was able to submit a new flag without any issues. It seems that the system is designed to prevent duplicate flag messages on the same post, even if the previous flag has been addressed.
I've gone ahead and tagged my post with bug. To avoid confusion, it would be useful if the error message provided more context, such as "You cannot use the same flag message as a previous flag on this post."
